# WPF inheritance issue

Tags: inheritance, avaloniaui

I have a weird inheritance issue where my (custom) control does not work, it just shows absolutely nothing even though NavigationButton extends the Button control. When I change the "components:NavigationButton" to "Button" it works like expected again.

There are no compile errors or anything similar, not even warnings, it just does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <components:NavigationButton
        Content="{StaticResource Image.Chat}"
        Classes="NavButton"
        Click="Button_OnChat"/> <!-- Doesn't work even though NavigationButton is a button -->
    <Button 
        Content="{StaticResource Image.Explore}"
        Classes="NavButton"
        Click="Button_OnExplore"/> <!-- This works as expected and shows a clickable button with an icon -->
</DockPanel>
```

```
namespace Client.View.Components;
    
public class NavigationButton : Button { } // An interface is going to be added to make the two types distinguishable
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. `NavigationButton : Button` with `Content="some text"` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I have to provide a "StyleKey". Also my mistake for not saying I use AvaloniaUI rather than WPF, sorry =(

The below works:

```
public class NavigationButton : Button, IStyleable {
    public Type StyleKey => typeof(Button);
}
```